# Add include directories to AUTOMOC

Tags: c++, qt4, makefile, cmake, ros

I have a ROS package that includes QT4 GUIs. My code is in the folder 
`Project_name/src/test/*.cpp` 
and my includes in 
`Project_name/include/test/*.h`

Some qt4 mocs must be created as some header files contain Q_OBJECT in their classes.

I tried the 
`set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`
in the cmake file but as it seems it does not search the /include/test/ folder. AUTOMOC states that works either bu searching the source files for moc_****.cpp files or by examining the header files for Q_OBJECT.

I also tried to include a `moc_***.cpp` in a source file (for example `/src/test/a.cpp`). So it searched for `a.h` but could not find it in `include/test/a.h`.

I must note that if I remove the Q_OBJECT from the classes the compilation succeeds, as the include/ folder is added like this:
`include_directories( include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)`

Finally I've tried to use QT4_WRAP_CPP but for some reason it couldn't find the mocs as well   and the link failed (although in another project with the same parameters in the cmake file works :/)

***Edit :***
Found a solution. In added in the cpp file:

`#include "../../include/test/moc_a.cpp"`

and found the .h in include/test.

Though something tells me that it is not the correct way :P

Answer (score 8):

`#include "../../include/test/moc_a.cpp"` in cpp file works but not well for libraries that may be built sometimes as static libraries within bigger project and sometimes by themselves. The problem is that *include* directory can be created in a not-suitable location, which pollutes code, causes problems with VCS.

[qt_wrap_cpp](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aqt_wrap_cpp) works best for me. It supports both qt4 and qt5, does not require including moc in cpp file. The syntax:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) # including binary dir is
# necessary only if there are classes with Q_OBJECT macro declared in cpp
# files (these cpp files should also contain `# include "x.moc"` at the end).
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
include_directories(${Include_Directories})
set(Sources ${Sources_Path}/a.cpp ${Sources_Path}/b.cpp
     ... ${Sources_Path_z}/z.cpp)
qt_wrap_cpp(${Target_Name} Sources ${Headers_Path}/header1.hpp
            ${Headers_Path_2}/header2.hpp ... ${Headers_Path_N}/headerN.hpp)
add_library(${Target_Name} STATIC ${Sources})
# OR add_executable(${Target_Name} ${Sources})
```

Naturally, only headers that contain `Q_OBJECT` macro and are not in the same directory as corresponding sources must be passed to `qt_wrap_cpp`.

Comment: What to do if I'm globbing my sources? (That is a deliberate decision - we used to list them all by hand, but we have 10 people working on the project who keep forgetting to update the makefiles)

Comment: Glob your headers into qt_wrap_cpp?

Comment: You wrote "only headers that contain `Q_OBJECT` macro [...] must be passed to `qt_wrap_cpp`" in your answer so I assumed it won't work if some of the headers don't contain the Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: Most likely everything would work. I probably meant that other headers don't have to be passed.